# Does it matter if I don't explicitly cast an int to a char before comparison with a char?

Tags: c++

When comparing an int to a char, should I explicitly cast one of them, or let the compiler do it for me? Does it matter? Why?

E.g.

```
int i = 113;
char c = 'q';
if (static_cast<char>(i) == c)
    cout << "equal";
// OR
if (i == c)
    cout << "equal";
```

Comment: Normally there is no need for the cast. Read more about [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) (see point 4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it does matter in some cases due to [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) and the fact that explicit conversion of `int` to `char` truncates higher bytes. 
Basically, if you try to compare two number-like types of different sizes, there are certain rules by which they're converted to some "common type", which is typically enough to "fit" both types. But if you do explicit conversion, you may lose some information.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 113;
    char c = 'q';
    cout << (static_cast<char>(i) == c) << endl; // 1
    cout << (i == c) << endl; // 1

    i += 0x100; // i is now 369, but lower byte is 113.
    cout << (static_cast<char>(i) == c) << endl; // 1
    cout << (i == c) << endl; // 0
    return 0;
}
```

When you explicitly convert `int` to a `char`, higher bytes *typically* get truncated (as noted in the comments, it's implementation-defined). However, when you compare `int` with `char`, the latter gets automatically promoted to `int` and then two `ints` are compared.

In this particular case you may avoid explicit cast. However, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018933/767632), it's not always ideologically correct to do so, as in standard library characters stored in `int` are typically non-negative numbers (e.g. `0..255`), as opposed to `char`, which can be signed depending on the compiler/platform (e.g. `-128..127`). That will cause potential problems if there are non-ASCII characters in your comparison.

So, if you are absolutely sure that you will never ever need non-ASCII, you can avoid explicit casts. But if it's not the case (or if you want to get a good habit), it's better to think about conventions and convert `char` to `unsigned char` before comparing with `int`:

```
i == static_cast<unsigned char>(c)
```

Comment: conversion of `int` to `char` is implementation-defined. (Usually it is equivalent to "truncate higher bits", but that isn't a guarantee)

Comment: **−1** “suggest you avoiding explicit cast - it works without this”, no, in general it doesn't work without a bit of explicit conversion, with the common convention of representing `char` values as `int`, as e.g. required by the standard library's character classification functions such as `isalpha`. It's just that the OP's cast is wrong. A correct cast is required, in general.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf good point, but I thought that specifically `isalpha` and friends are not defined outside of `0..127`?

Comment: They're not defined for negative values, except `EOF`. Quoting cppreference.com: "The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char". They work fine for these positive values. But remember to call `setlocale` first.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf added clarification to my answer and linked it to yours.

Comment: @yeputons Isn't the signedness of char implementation defined?

Comment: @DanielGilbert fixed

Answer (score 2):

The cast in your example should go the other way, from `char` to `int`, *via* `unsigned char`.

---

The established very very strong convention for representing `char` values as `int`, in particular for functions such as [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha), is that a negative `char` value is represented as that value converted to `unsigned char`, a strictly non-negative value.

And for code adhering to this most common convention, the condition in

```
if (static_cast<char>(i) == c)
```

does entirely the wrong thing.

For example, with 8-bit bytes and two's complement signed `char` type, which is by far the most common, the `i` value 128 represents the `char` value -128. The condition above can then incorrectly yields `false` because you have implementation-defined behavior when the value doesn't fit in the casted-to signed type. The cast has then completely needlessly introduced a bug.

A correct condition instead promotes that `char` to `int`, via a detour that converts negative values to strictly non-negative ones:

```
using Byte = unsigned char;
//...

if( i == static_cast<Byte>( c ) )
```

In the case where `sizeof(int)` = 1, this condition still works, even when `char` is unsigned type.

---

The standard library's `char` classification functions have undefined behavior for negative arguments, except the special value `EOF`.

And so the call

```
isalpha( c )
```

will generally have undefined behavior, because usually `char` is a signed type, and negative values can occur, e.g. with Latin 1 encoding of `'Å'`.

It should instead be

```
using Byte = unsigned char;
//...
isalpha( static_cast<Byte>( c ) )
```

Comment: Sorry about the large number of self-corrections of this post. I was pretty tired; I hope I got it all right in the end. I'm going to relax noe, watching the Arrival movie with perhaps a cup of /coffee/.